# Corona SDK - Check if valid image file

Tags: lua, download, coronasdk, file-exists

I am working with the latest Corona SDK version. In my app I am loading an image over network.download(...). If the user is offline, I load a placeholder instead.

Sometimes the download fails in the middle or does not save the file correctly. If I then try to show the image with display.newImageRect() the warning is displayed: WARNING: scripts/scenes/game.lua:98: file 'test.png' does not contain a valid image

How can I catch this warning and display a placeholder instead? Checking fileExists() does not catch the corrupted file.

Thanks,
fj

Answer (score 1):

From Lua [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html)

> local status, err = pcall( functionName )
>
> The pcall function calls its first argument in protected mode, so that
> it catches any errors while the function is running. If there are no
> errors, pcall returns true, plus any values returned by the call.
> Otherwise, it returns false, plus the error message.

You can use `pcall` function to catches errors when creating image

```
local image

local status, err = pcall( function() image = display.newImage('img.png', 100, 100) end )

if status and image then
    print( 'no errors ' )
      -- no errors  
else
    print( 'errors ' )
      -- function raised an error: take appropriate actions 
end
```

What is more I put below example of use `network.download` from Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/download.html)

```
local function networkListener( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "Network error - download failed: ", event.response )
    elseif ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        print( "Progress Phase: began" )
    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
        print( "Displaying response image file" )
        myImage = display.newImage( event.response.filename, event.response.baseDirectory, 60, 40 )
        myImage.alpha = 0
        transition.to( myImage, { alpha=1.0 } )
    end
end
 
local params = {}
params.progress = true
 
network.download(
    "http://docs.coronalabs.com/images/simulator/image-mask-base2.png",
    "GET",
    networkListener,
    params,
    "helloCopy.png",
    system.TemporaryDirectory
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: It looks like the PCALL does not catch the error of a missing image. If the file does not exist, it does not catch the error...??